# Tomcat port problems unable to start the tomcat

Tags: java

Tried to solve `Tomcat` port problems but nothing helped me.

1. `Eclipse` work space changed
2. Removed `Tomcat` server from `Eclipse` and then freshly added with run time        environment
3. System restarted
4. Removed some plugins from eclipse work space.

**Questions**

Able to start the server from command prompt but not through Eclipse (I did not configure any other server in Eclipse). Please share your knowledge on this.

Across all the portals, I got the above mentioned steps to solve the `Tomcat` problems but those are not helpful to me.

**Environment**

- `Eclipse Neon`
- `Tomcat 7`.

Comment: What is the error in log? Is the port already in use?

Comment: Please provide more details. Did you see Catalina.log file after tomcat start from eclipse? Are there any exceptions? Are you sure you configured tomcat in eclipse correctly?

Comment: Try this remove tomcat, remove server runtime (i mean delete) and then reimport tomcat, this time before starting it double click on the tomcat and a configuration page will open, click on the Use tomcat installation. This should do the trick

Comment: Try to delete your eclipse metadata and re-create workspace. Then import Tomcat freshly. This maybe helpful.

Comment: Neither 'unable ' nor 'nothing helps me' nor 'not helpful to me' is a problem description. Without an actual error error message your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the port is already in use.
Go to your tomcat settings in eclipse and change the default port. This should make it to run.

Comment: Based on what evidence?

Comment: @EJP since the "port already in use" is the problem it is self evident that 2 applications are trying to run on the same port.Hence I suggested my friend to change the port for tomcat in eclipse.Don't you find the solution appropriate ?

Comment: It is highly likely, but 'port already in use' doesn't appear in the question, ergo it is not evidence, which is what I asked for.